# Does the WD Red Drive overheat when placed in a plastic HDD enclosure with small ventilation at the bottom?

Tags: linux

I have Odroid-U3 as my multipurpose server. Initially, I used a portable hard disk drive where I frequently encounter disconnections and reconnections. My friend recommended to me to use hard drive drive built for NAS purposes in which I bought WD Red Drive and HDD enclosure. Sadly. I am still experiencing the same problem.

Is it possible that the problem is an overheating issue? Is it harmful to the Red Drive to be enclosed by a plastic case with minimal ventilation and without cooling fans?